# Is there a way to display the latest blog post in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

In laravel 8, I wanted to show a single post at a specific place. When I add new post it & display post automatically like real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest post using below code

```php
Post::latest()->first();
```